# C# - Get array/collection of HTML tags that has runat="server" in it

Tags: c#

I have several anchor/link tags on my page that all of them has runat="server" and a specific ID on it, is there a way to get them to an Array and then loop through them?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: I´m new to C# and I have no idea at all of what kind class/library I need to use. The rest is just html code. And I didn´t ask FOR CODE I ask if there is a way to get them to an array since I´m not a c# programmer.

Comment: Put their id's in an array or autogenerate their id's and then assign them to the tags, in a loop

Comment: Thanks johnny 5, that was what I thought at first, but then I would need to hardcode all ID´s twice, in the html page and in the .cs page, If I could 'detect' all my anchor tags somehow in c# I would just loop through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but here's how I would do this:

Let's say tags in your page look like this:

```
<a id="id12345">Some Content </a>
```

Load the HTML file into memory with FileStream, the read the file line by line looking for tags with the id property.  When found, perform some string split operations and replacements.

I would use a List, but can use an array if you want.

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();

string line;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\\path\\to\\file", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("<div id="))
        {
            string[] split1 = line.Split('=');
            string[] split2 = split1[1].Split('>');
            //remove quotes
            ids.Add(split2[0].Replace('"', ' '));
        }
    }
}

//now look through the list
foreach(string s in ids)
{
    //do stuff

}
```

Comment: Although this works, I´m still trying to find a library that would let me control html elements better. Thanks gev125.

Comment: You might try the HtmlAgilityPack nuget package.  I've not messed it too much, but it might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Souds nice! I´ll have a look at it. Thanks!